# Changing Button Foreground using VisualStateManager in uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml

I try to change the button foreground color using visual sate manager its does not work at all.

```
   <Button x:Name="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                            Width="100" Background="#FF4F4F4F" 
                                            Height="50" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FF2F2F2F"
                                            Content="Cancel">
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Close"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Close"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    </Button>
```

please help me to work this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you do it in the control template instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not working because you were trying to set Color value for a Brush type.

Please create a Brush StaticResource using the color you need. And set the resource in animation.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBoxErrorThemeBrush" Color="Red" />

<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_TextBlock">
     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxErrorThemeBrush}"/>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Regards,

Jessie